# Can apt-config modify apt config?

Tags: apt

I have tried to change a apt config value with apt-config but without success:

```
apt-config -o APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade=1 shell
```

Is there a another program on Debian / Ubuntu with you can customize the configuration?

Comment: I do not understand what the -o option is for then. I can see some temporary effect: `$ apt-config -o APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade=1 dump | grep ^APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
$ apt-config dump | grep ^APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";`

Comment: BTW you could giveargument(s) for `dump`: `apt-config dump APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade` to restrict its output (though man page does not tell it currently)

Answer (score 5):

Nope, `apt-config` is read-only (as its `--help` will tell you):

```
 apt-config is a simple tool to read the APT config file
```

To persist an Apt configuration change, you need to edit/add to the configuration files in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`. Before you start creating new files, you might want to check to see if that variable has already been set. Here's a quick grep looking for "Periodic":

```
$ grep -R Periodic /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic:APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic:APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic:APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic:APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

This may differ from your computer so run it. If I were going to make any changes, I'd run `sudoedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`. Apt should pick those up the next time one of its commands runs.

---

**Note**: the above obviously applies to the apt.config side of things. There are other settings lurking around in `/etc/apt/` (the parent directory of above) that may be applicable if you're trying to set other things.

Comment: `apt-config --help` does not tell it is read-only (apt 1.2.29).

Comment: This answer is objectively wrong/outdated.

Answer (score 0):

apt-config is not read-only but does not document all options in --help

> apt 2.4.5 (amd64) Usage: apt-config [options] command
>
> apt-config is an interface to the configuration settings used by all
> APT tools, mainly intended for debugging and shell scripting.
>
> Most used commands:   shell - get configuration values via shell
> evaluation   dump - show the active configuration setting
>
> See apt-config(8) for more information about the available commands.
> Configuration options and syntax is detailed in apt.conf(5).
> Information about how to configure sources can be found in
> sources.list(5). Package and version choices can be expressed via
> apt_preferences(5). Security details are available in apt-secure(8).

Keywords "See apt-config(8) for more information". In other words the information displayed by `--help` is incomplete by design. Upon viewing the man page for apt-config vi `man apt-config` you see

> -o, --option
> Set a Configuration Option; This will set an arbitrary configuration option. The syntax is -o Foo::Bar=bar. -o and --option can be used multiple times to set different options.

Thus the op should have stated what error they were getting. I suppect its because `sudo` was not used to execute the command. This is required to modify any system wide configuration such that of apt.

Comment: op's command does give neither output nor error status, Command `apt-config -o APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade=1 shell var APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade` gives `var='1'` but what is the point?

Comment: The error code can help identify where a problem is happening. As far as the question does apt-config support this setting I guess it doesn't matter.